# What is the difference between id(obj) and ctypes.addressof(obj) in CPython

Tags: python, memory-management, ctypes

Say I define the following variable using [ctypes module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)

```
i = c_int(4)
```

and afterwards I try to find out the memory address of i using:

```
id(i)
```

or

```
ctypes.addressof(i)
```

which, at the moment, yield different values. Why is that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are suggesting should be the case is an implementation detail of CPython.

The [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#id) function:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime.
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** This is the address of the object in memory.

While they might be equivalent in CPython, this is not guaranteed to be true in other implementations of Python.

---

*Why are they different values, even in CPython?*

Note that a `c_int`:

- *is* a Python Object.  CPython's `id()` will return the address of this.
- *contains* a 4-byte C-compatible `int` value. `ctypes.addressof()` will return the address of this.

The metadata in a Python object takes up space. Because of this, that 4-byte value probably won't live at the very beginning of the Python object.

Look at this example:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> i = ctypes.c_int(4)
>>> hex(id(i))
'0x22940d0'
>>> hex(ctypes.addressof(i))
'0x22940f8'
```

We see that the `addressof` result is only 0x28 bytes higher than the result of `id()`.  Playing around with this a few times, we can see that this is always the case.  Therefore, I'd say that there are 0x28 bytes of Python object metadata preceding the actual `int` value in the overall `c_int`.

In my above example:

```
   c_int
 ___________
|           |   0x22940d0   This is what id() returns
| metadata  |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|___________|
|   value   |   0x22940f8   This is what addressof() returns
|___________|
```

---

**Edit:**

In the CPython implementation of ctypes, the base [`CDataObject`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h#l57) (2.7.6 source) has a `b_ptr` member that points to the memory block used for the object's C data:

```c
union value {
                char c[16];
                short s;
                int i;
                long l;
                float f;
                double d;
#ifdef HAVE_LONG_LONG
                PY_LONG_LONG ll;
#endif
                long double D;
};

struct tagCDataObject {
    PyObject_HEAD
    char *b_ptr;                /* pointer to memory block */
    int  b_needsfree;           /* need _we_ free the memory? */
    CDataObject *b_base;        /* pointer to base object or NULL */
    Py_ssize_t b_size;          /* size of memory block in bytes */
    Py_ssize_t b_length;        /* number of references we need */
    Py_ssize_t b_index;         /* index of this object into base's
                                   b_object list */
    PyObject *b_objects;        /* dictionary of references we need 
                                   to keep, or Py_None */
    union value b_value;
};
```

[`addressof`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l1632) returns this pointer as a Python integer:

```c
static PyObject *
addressof(PyObject *self, PyObject *obj)
{
    if (CDataObject_Check(obj))
        return PyLong_FromVoidPtr(((CDataObject *)obj)->b_ptr);
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                    "invalid type");
    return NULL;
}
```

Small C objects use the default 16-byte `b_value` member of the `CDataObject`. As the example above shows, this default buffer is used for the `c_int(4)` instance. We can turn ctypes on itself to introspect `c_int(4)` in a 32-bit process:

```python
>>> i = c_int(4)
>>> ci = CDataObject.from_address(id(i))

>>> ci
ob_base: 
    ob_refcnt: 1
    ob_type: py_object(<class 'ctypes.c_long'>)
b_ptr: 3071814328
b_needsfree: 1
b_base: LP_CDataObject(<NULL>)
b_size: 4
b_length: 0
b_index: 0
b_objects: py_object(<NULL>)
b_value: 
    c: b'\x04'
    s: 4
    i: 4
    l: 4
    f: 5.605193857299268e-45
    d: 2e-323
    ll: 4
    D: 0.0

>>> addressof(i)
3071814328
>>> id(i) + CDataObject.b_value.offset
3071814328
```

This trick leverages the fact that `id` in CPython returns the base address of an object.

Comment: Ok, but why does it not even hold in cpython, as documented?

Comment: adjusted the title accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @NiklasB. Updated my answer. It's because `addrsesof` returns the address of the actual `int` inside the `c_int` object, while `id()` (on CPython) returns the address of the python object itself. There seems to be a fixed 0x28 offset in my implementation.

Comment: @eryksun Excellent next step in the analysis of this behavior. I don't have time at the moment to incorporate that information. Feel free to add it to mine, or write your own answer (which I would definitely up-vote).