# Why does ctypes.addressof() not match id() for ctypes.Structure objects?

Tags: python, ctypes, cpython

This is something I've been stumped with for a while now so any input would be appreciated.

Running python 2.7 (cpython), consider the following ctypes.Structure representing a SCSI generic IO struct:

```
import ctypes
class SGIOHeader(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('interface_id', ctypes.c_int),
        ('dxfer_direction', ctypes.c_int),
        ('cmd_len', ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ('mx_sb_len', ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ('iovec_count', ctypes.c_ushort),
        ('dxfer_len', ctypes.c_uint),
        ('dxferp', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('cmdp', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('sbp', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('timeout', ctypes.c_uint),
        ('flags', ctypes.c_uint),
        ('pack_id', ctypes.c_int),
        ('usr_ptr', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('status', ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ('masked_status', ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ('msg_status', ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ('sb_len_wr', ctypes.c_ubyte),
        ('host_status', ctypes.c_ushort),
        ('driver_status', ctypes.c_ushort),
        ('resid', ctypes.c_int),
        ('duration', ctypes.c_uint),
        ('info', ctypes.c_uint)]
```

If I instantiate an object using the above class, I tend to observe that what is returned by ctypes.addressof() is no where near what is returned by calling id() on the object:

```
>>> sgio = SGIOHeader()
>>> hex(id(sgio))
'0x10eb5ed40'
>>> hex(ctypes.addressof(sgio))
'0x7fdeca700130'
```

I understand that there should be a delta between id() and ctypes.addressof() corresponding to the metadata necessary for reference counting and object identification. What I do not understand is why the python address of the object is so far from the memory address of the backing structure?

The reason this is a problem is because if I were to try to issue an ioctl using the ctypes.addressof() value, I will always get an EFAULT because the object is deemed outside of my process' address space. If the object lives in the heap, how can its backing address be so far away from its identity? What am I misunderstanding regarding how python objects are laid out in memory? Are there different addressing schemes (it seems that I'm either getting a 32 bit or 64 bit value)?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600052/what-is-the-difference-between-idobj-and-ctypes-addressofobj-in-cpython

Comment: Just for the record, I was actually running into the classic ctypes "if you don't specify the type of function arguments, they will default to 32 bit integers issue"... seems silly but oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the C structure modelled and the Python object that proxies for it are two separate concepts.

`id()` gives you the memory address of the Python proxy object, `ctypes.addressof()` gives you the address of the actual C struct. You can't pass the Python object to other C code, but you *can* pass the C struct to other C code.